# pkgbuild created package does not install correctly

Tags: macos, install

Have now used pkgbuild/productbuild to create a product archive, consisting of three packages (application, uninstaller, KEXT), that according to installer installs fine, no errors.

The KEXT is correctly placed in /Library/Extensions and postinstall script loads it nicely.

But my applications are not moved to the /Applications/Company/ folder. The folder is created, but the applications are not placed there.

The process of doing the component plist + distribution XML is so utterly simple so I just cannot fathom what the h*ll can go wrong ?

The package **can** be "installed" via Pacifist, albeit then the postinstall script is not executed.

Help?

Update:

Analyze phase (application resides in ./pkgbuild/app_path/ folder):

```
pkgbuild --analyze --root "./pkgbuild/app_path/" app.plist
```

Build phase:

```
pkgbuild --root "./pkgbuild/app_path/" \
         --component-plist ./app.plist \
         --install-location "/Applications/Company/" \
         --identifier "com.company.myapp.pkg" \
         --version "1.0" \
         app.pkg
```

Then the product archive, step 1:

```
productbuild --synthesize --package app.pkg distribution.xml
```

distribution.xml is then modified with correct background image, license, etc.

Step 2:

```
productbuild --distribution ./distribution.xml output.pkg
```

(I omitted the KEXT package as that works perfectly)

When installing "output.pkg", folder /Applications/Company/ is created but is empty.

SOLVED (see Grahams answer below):

By setting **BundleIsRelocatable** in the component plist files to **false**, the applications are put into the correct place.

Viewing the installer log, the application got "relocated" to where my Xcode project built the app, but still create the /Application/Company folder. A "slightly" peculiar behaviour I would say.

OSX version is 10.11.1.

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add the details of the application installer package? What flags and options did you use? What does the post-install script do? Ideally an installer should not need a post-install script.

Comment: Ok, will do. The postinstall script loads an installed KEXT, so it is needed.

Comment: Is `app.pkg` the expected size after calling `pkgbuild`? Does `app.pkg` work when installed on its own?

Comment: Size is correct (~ 3MB), and no, it does not work on its own either.

Comment: I've now taken a random .app, went through the above motions, and get exactly the same result. Folder in /Applications is created but has no content :(

Comment: A couple of things to narrow the scope. On what exact build of OS X are you getting an error? This also needs an edit to make it less about troubleshooting or a possible solution in the body. If you wish to propose a partial answer - move the "solved-ish" text into a proper solution and explain why it's not a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks, bmike, I'll change the soved-ish text, because Grahams answer is the correct one. My problem mainly lies within the "fact" that Installer.app relocated my app to where Xcode built the app. I think this is a weird behaviour, but it can be mitigated with the BundleIsRelocatable flag. OSX is latest El Capitan.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Moved Applications

The Installer is likely updating the first copy of the application it finds and not the application in the default install location.

This behaviour is deliberate and allows users to move applications, while retaining the ability to use Installer packages to apply updates.

As a developer you probably have numerous copies of the target application on your Mac. It is likely the last copy you – or Xcode – launched is the one being updated. This can include copies within hidden build folders.

### Enforce the Location with `BundleIsRelocatable`

Setting `BundleIsRelocatable` flag to `false` forces **Installer.app** to use the exact path provided by the package.

Without this flag set, the Installer.app will search the target Mac for matching applications and write the new copy to the discovered location.

- Try your installer with a clean Mac with a fresh copy of OS X.
- Look closely at the log output from Installer.app or `installer`; you will see entries regarding the search and final location of the relocated application.

### Report the Bug

That the Installer still created the parent company folder does feel like an error. Please [report a bug with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com).